# Does Google has a page where they show when an Android version isn't supported anymore?

Tags: updates, security

We are in doubt of supporting a device running an older version of Android. I looked everywhere on the internet, but there seems to be zero information from Google how long they will make security patches for a certain Android version.

I did find the Wikipedia 'Android Version History' page, but it's unknown where they got this information from.

My question: does Google has a page where they show when an Android version isn't supported anymore?

Thanks in advance,

Gerjan

Comment: Look into the security bulletins to see what versions Google patches. Take the [March 2018 for example](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2018-03-01). It contains the info that patches for Android down to 6 and 5.1 were provided.